# Cannot find tensorflow after installing with pip for gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, cudnn

I am on a docker image,  so I can not access the "outside" of the docker image. I want to install tensorflow with gpu support so used:

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

cudnn and CUDA is installed and working. An old version (0.11) is available in the image and is running with CUDA and cudnn just fine, but I need to upgrade to version 1 or higher. I have two Nvidia Titans.

After using the shown pip command I use the following script to see if I have GPU support enabled, and also look at nvidia-smi:

```
import tensorflow as tf


# Creates a graph.
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
  a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
  b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
  c = tf.matmul(a, b)
# Creates a session with log_device_placement set to True.
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
# Runs the op.
print sess.run(c)
```

After this I only get the output

> No module named tensorflow

If I check the pip list with:

```
pip list | grep tensorflow
```

I get the output:

> tensorflow-gpu (1.0.1)

Is it a simple wrong import?

If I use the non-gpu-support install `pip install tensorflow` the above code gives:

> Device mapping: no known devices.

Which of course is due to no support of the gpu. So to summarize, how do I get the GPU Version of tensorflow to work with a simple pip install and a version above 1.0 ?

Comment: I would check full install log of pip with `pip install tensorflow-gpu --log`

Comment: You definitely need the GPU version. The "no module" error seems to indicate that you might be using wrong version of python. Are you sure that pip you are using to install tensorflow is using the same python that you are running the code with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing it with

```
conda install tensorflow-gpu
```

resolved all issues.

Comment: thank you, i should have tried this before spending 2 days in vain trying to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Activate tensorflow with:

```
>>>source activate tensorflow
```

Comment: Thank you, This looks like the solution to the original problem, but if I run this script I get an error: File "/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/install.py, line 130, in symlink_fn(root_file,prefix_file) (last error from the traceback). Is this a new error which should be put in a new question?

Comment: I installed it now with conda install tensorflow-gpu and everything works like I want it, too.